# Can I use Mongodb with mithril js or vue js?

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, mithril.js

I would like to find out how to connect a database (e.g. Mongodb or MySql) to mithril js or vue js.
Any useful link or tutorials?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mithril is a tiny framework that focuses on MV? There are a minimal number of helpers built-in, such as basic **AJAX**, basic **promises**, and basic **routing**. If you need more functionality, such as database connectivity, you are responsible for writing plain old javascript. To my knowledge there are no publicly available examples of people using Mithril with mongodb. You will need to write a server-side script (python/php/javascript) to make your DB requests. You can then use Mithril's `m.request` helper to get the data to your app. I would **check the mongodb website** for such scripts.

This will be of little help to you, but the Mithril wiki has a section on database connectivity. Maybe in the future there will be more community contributions added.
https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/wiki/Community-Projects#databases